# Context switches between functions and slots in a single thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5

I am implementing a small project where I am extensively using QThreads and signals/slots (and basically Qt 5). I can say I have a fair idea about how signals/slots work along with QThreads. (I have gone through all important material on StackExchange as well as these links "You are doing it wrong" and its update [You were not doing so wrong](http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html). I have also gone through [Most correct way to use QThread](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)) I am convinced about my design that I will have to subclass QThread but also add slots to the subclass (which I know will run in separate threads.)

My calling thread (object on the thread) hosts such slots of at least three different classes along with its own utility functions. My question is:
**How the context switches between different slots and functions affined to a thread are handled? Will there be a context switch if one of the function has sleep or wait called (should be right?)? Secondly is there anything specific behaviour for QThreads?**

If there is nothing specific to Qt or QThreads, still I would like to know about this behaviour in general.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, if you call sleep or wait in a slot, the thread won't be able to do anything else during that call. You can call `QApplication::processEvents()` in a slot to give Qt a chance to process pending events, possibly invoking other slots recursively. If you don't use this function, Qt will not execute any slots (in this thread) until currently running slot is finished. Note that slots in a `QThread`'s subclass are by default executed in the main thread because `QThread` objects belong to it.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, even if my run function is sleeping, no other slots can execute on the thread even if I have moved them to the thread as of slots of worker objects and not thread object itself. Am I correct?

So there are two approaches.
1. Subclass the thread and let the slots in the thread run in the owner of the thread object and of course `run()` method will execute in separate thread.
2. Subclass the thread and add requisite slots via worker objects and move these worker objects to this thread itself.

I think I am creating confusion for myself.

Comment: I don't understand you well. Could you describe more specifically what are you trying to do? Note that reimplementing `QThread::run` is often redundant, and if you do so, you still need to start an event loop in it manually (as base class implementation does). Otherwise, Qt won't be able to execute any slots in that thread at all.

Comment: Yes I am aware about explicitly calling exec from subclass of QThread. In simple terms what I want to do is following. Subclass QThread as there is one continuous long running procedure. Then write some worker object which will have slots which should ideally execute on above thread as well. I can move this worker object to the thread in some public method of my subclass and connect the slots to signals before starting the thread.

Comment: How do you plan to call `exec()` and run your long operation in one thread simultaneously? It's not possible. If you call `exec()`, control flow won't return to you until the event loop is terminated. Subclassing QThread won't change anything in that, so it's simpler to move your long operation in a slot of a worker object. Or you can put the operation in `QThread::run`, but that thread won't be able to process events and call slots.

Comment: Great. Now I understand the difference clearly. So even though it is technically possible to make threadproc (run function) and slots run in a same thread, it's actually useless due to zero practicality. Thanks a lot @PavelStrakhov. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're confused by the cooperative multitasking exhibited by typical event driven applications, with their run-to-completion event handlers. This is how WIN16, GEM, Atari TOS, and other such platforms appeared to multitask with **no** context switches at all.

I'll attempt to clear this confusion after exposing the necessary background to this story.

A context switch is a way to reuse an available core to run another thread when the current one has used up its timeslice or is sleeping. It is an optimization of sort, when you're short on cores. Yes, it is an implementation detail of the platform that your code runs on. It is not even a *necessary* one: you cannot tell if your platform context-switches or not just by looking at it (really, other then side channel attacks).

`QThread` is just a thin thread controller object. The controlled thread is a platform object and Qt does nothing to alter its behavior. The `QThread::run` behaves just like it would on a native platform thread, because that's where it runs.

The `QThread::run` method only spins (`exec()` in Qt parlance) an event loop (of course it won't do it anymore if your reimplementation doesn't).

An event loop waits for events to arrive in the queue, and then notifies the target `QObject`s of their reception.

The cross-thread (queued) signal-slot connections are implemented by leveraging events. Upon emission, the signal copies its arguments and posts them in a `QMetaCallEvent` to each queued-connected receiver object. Since these objects live in another thread, the event loop running in their thread will get woken up. It will then pick up the event and have it handled by the target object's `event` method. Specifically, `QObject::event` implementation knows how to deal with the `QMetaCallEvent`: it will execute the slot call.

Thus, **queued slot calls are acting as event handlers**, since they are invoked as an effect of `QObject::event()` being invoked by the event loop. Whenever a queued slot executes, the call stack looks as follows:

- your slot method,
- `QObject::event()`
- ...
- `QEventLoop::exec()`
- `QThread::run`
- platform-specific thread function.

So, how can events and event handlers give an *impression* of multiprocessing? That's because all event handlers are **running to completion**. They never sleep nor block, they simply execute the short actions they need to, and immediately return to the event loop.

This behavior will be broken as soon as your event handlers become blocking. Since slots called via queued connections (cross-thread) are effectively `QMetaCallEvent` handlers, if you block/sleep/wait in them, you're sleeping the entire thread. Suppose you call `QThread::sleep` in your slot. The call stack then is:

- platform-specific implementation of sleep,
- `QThread::sleep()`,
- your slot,
- ...
- `QThread::run()`.

At this point, the thread simply isn't runnable. If the platform so chooses, *another* thread might run on the same core, to make use of it, but that is the platform's optional optimization that you have little control over.

1. How the context switches between different slots and functions affined to a thread are handled?

   There are none. Or, more specifically, as long as there are `QMetaCallEvent` events stored in the event queue for a given thread, and as long as that thread is runnable, it will simply keep executing the queued slot calls. On an otherwise idle multicore machine, you can keep a thead executing queued slot calls with no additional context switches.

   If your slot sleeps or waits, the entire thread sleeps or waits.
2. Will there be a context switch if one of the function has sleep or wait called?

   Not necessarily so. You're presuming that the operating system's implementation of interruptible wait will preempt your thread. This might be the case, or it might not be the case. Whatever happens, of course, your thread is sleeping at that point and obviously nothing else happens within it while it is sleeping.

Comment: There couldn't have been better explanation! Bang on! Thanks a lot!!